# Why is reading from a map returning null?

Tags: kotlin

I'm having trouble understanding why `a` is null. I want to be able to cast the value for `"abc"` back to a double, but I'm getting an error that it is `null`.

```
val params: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
params["abc"] = 10.4

println("${params["abc"]}")         // prints "10.4"

val a: Any? = params["abc"]

println(a)                          // prints "null"
println(params["abc"] is Double)    // prints "true"
```

Maybe this problem is happening because I am running it as a Kotlin script `.kts` as a scratch file in IntelliJ. Another thing I noticed is that if I use `val params: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf("abc" to 10.4)` it works as expected.

Comment: It doesn't reproduce https://pl.kotl.in/VqibwjqNU

Comment: @IR42 thanks for showing that. It must be something with the way the code is running in my IDE. I thought I was doing something wrong with my map.

Comment: Did you tried using the interactive mode in the intellij idea / android studio, to see the what actions are performed with code in the scratch console?

Comment: Is it possible that the line setting `a` has a misspelling in the string index?  (I'm sure you'd have spotted it if it was obvious, but it could theoretically include a zero-width space or some other character that's hard to see.)